# Can't render page, or DOMDocumentFragment breaks on <script> tags, or something

Tags: php, javascript, domdocument

After some trial and error, I've come to notice that my Template engine fails on template files that contain `<script>` tags. This is clearly a huge problem, but I can't seem to figure out why it's failing.

It's very peculiar too, the manner with which it fails. With the `<script>` tags commented out, the page loads normally, however with the `<script>` tags uncommented, the page loads, and performing a **View Source** shows that the entire page has loaded, though nothing is rendered in the browser. The **Firebug** DOM inspector, shows a head tag, and an empty body.

The stranger part (I think at least) is that these script tags are targeting external files. If there was in-page scripting outside of a CDATA section, I could understand some unexpected results.

I'd post the code used, but it's extremely long and I wouldn't know where to start, ie; where the issue is, if in fact there even is one.

In short, my template engine creates a single `DOMDocument` object, and then creates `DOMDocumentFragment` objects to manage parts of the template. The first parsing iteration typically loads the entire template file into a fragment, and then it works down the tree based on certain parameters, looking for certain tags.

**TL;DR: Does anyone know why the PHP DOM classes may be failing to build the page properly due to script tags? If I enclose them in `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` tags, it does nothing. Only when I remove or comment out the tags does a browser load *and* render the page.**

Comment: Can you at please give us the most minimalistic code reproduction?

Comment: I would re-route the main power conduits to circuit "B". Or, try inverse phasing.

Comment: This won't directly answer your question, although it may be related to your troubles. You seem to not be totally clear on what is serverside(php) and what is clientside(html,css,javascript). I say this because you mention php as a possible cause of this problem despite seeing the html source present in its entirety. It's very very important you understand the distinction as a web developer, as it will cause you endless confusion. Your problem needs to be found on the clientside, before a solution is possible.

Comment: **@chris**; Yes I was typing furiously and didn't elaborate where necessary. The DOM objects are injecting namespace attributes and doing odd things with empty nodes, especially script tags. DOM builds my tree, effs it up, and sends. When the tree gets received and loaded by a browser, for some reason the malformed nodes are completely irrenderable, breaking the page entirely.

Comment: Also, I've noticed, going along with my last comment, if I simply put a comment in the script tag, it works... Sort of. `<script type="..." src="...">//foo</script>` It still appears to break, perhaps because the `DOCTYPE` is stripped, but this is certainly no solution.

Comment: **@Pointy**; I'm about to re-route the main power conduits to my brain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the content of the script tag wrapped in a CDATA block?  If it isn't, the DOM will attempt to parse its contents and fail.  Make sure all script code is wrapped in CDATA blocks, and that the DOM parser is configured to output CDATA blocks (otherwise the output will contain empty script tags).

I would also advise putting as much of the script code off-page as possible and placing it in its own files that you then link to with `<script src="/path/to/script.js"></script>` markup.  This avoids the DOM parsing problem, and has the additional benefit that the browser only needs to load the code once and can keep it cached in subsequent page views.

Comment: **@Gordon**; Yes, the scripts are already externalized. That's part of my confusion, as there's no scripting to break the `DOM` object parsing. It's only empty script tags with the appropriate attributes. This project appears to have a weak foundation. I'm starting to think scrap. At least I learned alot about PHP's `DOM` implementation and XSD.

Comment: What happens if you delete or comment the script tags out?  Does the document get parsed correctly in that case?  If you're using an XML serialization of HTML (XHTML) then you might also be able to try using PHP's XML parsing libraries in place of DOMDocument.